# Cоздание поля "Код заказчика" и "Код товара"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, entity-framework, getter

Нужна помощь в создание поля "Код заказчика" и "Код товара".

Пишу приложение интернет-магазина в *Visual Studio* (MVC). Использую подход Code-first. В этом деле я новичок и только со всем разбираюсь.

Для моего проекта нужны эти 2 поля. Формат поля "Код заказчика" - «ХХХХ-ГГГГ» где Х – число, ГГГГ – год в котором зарегистрирован заказчик.
Поле "Код товара" - формат «XX-XXXX-YYXX» где Х – число , Y- заглавная буква английского алфавита.

Читал про геттеры и сеттеры на MSDN, но не нашёл не чего похожего. Подскажите как их сделать, лучше примером.

---

**перенесено из «ответа«**:

Сущности Order и Item уже описаны, как и другие.
Код заказчика.

```
[Bind(Exclude = "OrderID")]
public partial class Order
{


    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Дата заказа")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Дата доставки")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public System.DateTime OrderDateShiping { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Имя пользователя")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Ваше имя")]
    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Вашу фамилию")]
    [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Адресс")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Ваш адресс")]
    [StringLength(70)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Город")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Ваш город")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Область")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите область")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите индекс")]
    [DisplayName("Индекс")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Страна")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите страну")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Номер телефона")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Ваш номер телефона")]
    [StringLength(24)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Ваш Emal")]
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",
        ErrorMessage = "Поле Email введено не корректно.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Сумма")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
```

Код товара.

```
[Bind(Exclude = "ItemID")]
public partial class Item
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Наименование")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите наименование")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Бренд")]
    public int BrandID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Категория")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Стоимость")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите стомость")]
    [Range(0.01, 100.00,
        ErrorMessage = "Цена должна быть от 0.01 до 100.00")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Логотип")]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string ItemArtUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
```

код StoreEntities

```
public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categorys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
```

Так же реализованы все операции. Моя проблема в том, что нужно добавить поле Code, но я не понимаю как его сделать таким форматом. Вот и прошу помощи с этим полем, подсказать как его сделать или если есть возможность дать похожий пример.

Comment: Я искренне уверен, что вам для начала следует ознакомиться с программированием как таковым. Далее - с методикой разработки. Потом - с технологиями, которые вы хотите использовать. Перескочить - не получится.  После этого для вас станет очевидно, что для того, чтобы иметь два этих плоских _поля_, вам надо как минимум описать _сущности_ "заказчик" и "товар", в каждом из которых определить другие релевантные поля.  В подобном же виде вопрос бесполезен и не имеет ответа в частности потому, что его следует читать так: _"реализуйте мою задачу, не зная её определения"_.

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать модель
2. Создать свойства модели
3. Повесить атрибуты на свойства модели
4. В контролере передать во View() модель
5. В самой View выводить элементы модели, форматирование для ввода делается JS